# toISOString is not showing the millisec

Tags: javascript, datetime, isodate

We are getting the timestamp String as **2022-02-23T09:41:57Z** but as per the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) it should have the milliseconds also in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
The code is

> (new Date()).toISOString()

But next request is having timestamp as **2022-02-23T09:41:57.003Z**

The Browser detail

> "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.3 Safari/605.1.15"

Why are the milliseconds not coming? But in my browser

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.3 Safari/605.1.15

I printed this in the loop it prints .000Z for millisec, is it depends on OS or Browser

Comment: `is it depends on OS or Browser` yes ... try a different browser, then you'll know

Comment: tried in chrome it's giving .000Z

Comment: must be the OS then